# Inverse Association Rules

Tags: association-rules

Association rules are a very common technique when you want to figure out which events happens together (like burger and bread mostly sell together). In marketing this technique is used to find out the complimentary products.

I am looking for a technique to extract the "Substitute Products" which is like Inverse Association rules to find out which events are less likely to happen together. Are there any algorithms or techniques available in Spark, R, Python, etc. for this?

Thanks, Amir

Answer (score 0):

FWIK from using it, the algorithm in [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si) add-on for [association rules mining](http://orange3-associate.readthedocs.org/) (a Python package) works like this: if you have a dense table of transactions where a 1 in the table denotes that a product was bought and 0 that it was not, then the mined association rules also contain products that were explicitly not bought, e.g. `bread=1, burger=0 ==> milk=1`

If, however, the products table is passes as a sparse basket with non-empty values representing the product counts, then the generated rules don't contain any such negative (`burger=0`) checks.

Hope this helps.